# Mono Droid - > Deploy -> Select Device not working for emulators is there an alternative way?

Tags: android

I have installed Mono for Android setup, I was able to follow through the Hello World example, I have the Android SDK Manager working with my AVM's I can even start an emulator when prompted during deploy -> select device selection. Howerver, once the emulator starts it never shows in my Select Device list, so I can't really test anything by pushing it to the emulator.

Am I missing anything? Is there any other way to deploy a compiled package to android emulator when using VS2010/Mono setup?

Thanks a lot for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar behaviours in Netbeans. Here is what I do:

1. After the emulator has started the first time, it is "locked". Just unlock it by dragging the green thingy from left to right. Then just press "RUN" again in the IDE.
2. Sometimes, it works to just hit "Run" again without changing anything. Just wait a minute after trying the first time.

I discovered that being patient with the emulator often helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I managed to get that working. To resolve that I have to start the Emulator through SDK manager. Then another entry is showing in the Deploy window "emulator xxxx". I managed to deploy to that instance. Starting emulators from the IDE doesn't seem to refresh the list ... txh

Comment: Could you write that for an answer and accept it? Otherwise your question will remain filed as "open" ...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to be running VisualStudio as an admin in order to get the running emulators to appear in the list.